# Is a RKHS defined using a feature map over another RKHS bigger than the latter RKHS?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, embeddings, kernels

I am interested in learning more about what happens when 'composing' two reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (RKHS).

Let $\phi\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $X=[-1,1]^d$. Suppose we have two RKHSs with the first RKHS $\mathcal{H}_1$ both over $X$ given by
$$
  k_1(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\mathbb{R}}\phi(w^\intercal x)+b)\phi(w^\intercal y+b)d\pi(w,b) \\
  ||f||_{\mathcal{H}_1} = \inf\{\;||\alpha_f||^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\mathbb{R}, \pi)}\;|\; f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\mathbb{R}}\alpha_f(w,b)\phi(w^\intercal x+b)d\pi(w,b) \;\}
$$
and the second RKHS $\mathcal{H}_2$ given by
$$
  k_2(x,y) = \int_{\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathbb{R}}\phi(z(x)+b)\phi(z(y)+b)d\rho(z,b) \\
  ||f||_{\mathcal{H}_2} = \inf\{\;||\beta_f||^2_{L^2(\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathbb{R},\rho)}\;|\; f(x) = \int_{\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathbb{R}}\beta_f(z,b)\phi(z(x)+b)d\rho(z,b) \;\}
$$
where $\pi$ and $\rho$ are probability measures over $\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathbb{R}$ respectively.

For $\phi$ you can imagine a function like a Gaussian or a hyperbolic tangent. $\pi$ and $\rho$ are free to choose.

**Question**: Do we have $\mathcal{H}_1\hookrightarrow\mathcal{H}_2$?

**Partial answer/observations**:

- Picking $\phi=0$ or $\phi(x)=x$ yields trivial instances.
- By Mercer's theorem we know that both $k_1$ and $k_2$ have an eigenvalue/eigenfunction expansion. Hence, it would be sufficient to show that all eigenfunctions of $k_1$ are elements of $\mathcal{H}_2$.
- We only have to look at functions with norm 1, since we can define $\beta_f$ as $\beta_f(z,b) := ||f||\tilde{\beta_f}(w,b)$ and divide both sides by $||f||$.
- It might be sufficient (may not be) to consider functions of the form $f(x) = \int_{\mathcal{H}_1}\tilde{\beta_f}(z)\phi(z(x))d\tilde{\rho}(z)$, since constant functions are part of $\mathcal{H}_1$.